# lazy load using Requirejs and AngularAMD

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-amd

Trying to implement lazy load using [Requirejs and AngularAMD](http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home) utility with angularjs.

*Everything is fine.*

The problem is *I have number of controllers*, so when I want to load `addUserCtrl.js`, it get loaded. I am happy that other controller js not loaded yet.

Now the issue rises: when I load `allUsersCtrl.js`, it get loaded, but `addUserCtrl.js` is also still loaded. So what I want the **previous controllers js should not be in loaded state.** Because the application is having number of controllers.

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: Your question is unclear. Assume that there are 2 controllers: `controller1` and `controller2`. When `controller1` is loaded, the other controller isn't loaded. Now after that state, you want to load `controller2` ? But during the load, `controller1` should be unloaded ? Is this what you want ?

Comment: Yes. When we look at HTML source : we see the script tag get added. As we go loading controllers, script tags get added.

Comment: see I have/had made controllers as per functionality.
suppose i am doing functionality1 , so i need controller1
now i am doing functioanlity 2, so i need controller2.
then what about that controller1? that I dnt need anymore.

Comment: See answer at https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD/issues/149